# set value input does not work (using javascript), has validation

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to assign a value to an input on netflix login page, using javascript, the problem is that it does not take the value, since the input has validation by keypress.

I'm using CefSharp (c#) to inject the code

```
browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('id_userLoginId').focus();");
browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById(\"id_userLoginId\").value = \"test@text\";");
```

the value is assigned, but when the focus is lost, it disappears

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: I solved it using selenium, with the "send key" function